# Real time use of REST web service in web application

Tags: rest

I am new to REST and watched few videos and read few blogs on REST webservice and I came to know that generally people are using REST for supporting multiple devices like mobile and computer etc.

Now consider I am developing order management system and I want to support both computer as well as tablets. If in m traditional web application, I am using Spring MVC at front end, how REST will fit here so that it will support both the kind of devices.

One more doubt is, whatever examples I have browsed, it return html or json data. I want to develop the application the way spring MVC or struts works like returning name of jsp and jsp will be rendered with dynamic data (instead of returning string represented html).

I hope my question is clear. Please bear me as my questions are vague but I am looking from implementation and design point of view.

Comment: for java, you could try [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/); [RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) and [SpringRest](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/). You could read the guide how they handle the dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

Just to start REST isn't anything to do with supporting mobile browsers. It is the architecture pattern HTTP follows. The Web had been REST since the early days.

I'm guessing what you mean is a server that returns light weight JSON that the client renders into HTML rather than the server returning HTML directly to browser. To do that you can use a java script framework that expects JSON data and that has a template engine to generate HTML on the fly in the browser. I think Anglar and Ember work like this.

Though I would only do this if you need to, and you don't need to do this just to support mobile browsers, you can support mobile just by making sure your CSS is responsive.